# JavaScript: How to change property of variables stored in an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array that contains variables that are used to control a template.

```
divisionsListToHide: ['showActivitiesList',
                                'showAssignActionplanDiv',
                                'showPropertiesListDiv',
                                'showAddActivityDiv',
                                'showCurrentActivity',
                                'editCurrentActivity'
                                ],
```

I want to call a method that will set all variables contained in the divisionsListToHide array to false, i.e.

```
this.showAssignActionplanDiv = false;
this.showPropertiesListDiv= false;
```

I am trying to create a method (function) to accomplish this:

```
hideDivisions: function()
        {
            for(var i = 0;i<this.divisionsListToHide.length;i++)
            {
                var xx = 'this.' + this.divisionsListToHide[i];  // e.g. this.showActivitiesList
                console.log(xx);                
                eval(xx) = false;


            }
        },
```

I was hoping to accomplish this through eval(), however, it displays "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment". Any suggestion, how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please try searching prior to asking. There are hundreds of similar questions with detailed answers here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is an object, and you can access its properties in two ways:
`this.propertyName` and `this["propertyName"]`. These two ways are the same, except the second one can be used with a variable just like in your case:

```js
var prop = "propertyName";
this[prop] = false;  // is equal to this["propertyName] = false, which is equal to this.propertyName = false
```

So try this:

```js
hideDivisions: function()
    {
        for (var i = 0; I <this.divisionsListToHide.length; i++)
        {
            this[this.divisionsListToHide[i]] = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.